# Dragging one shapefile into QGIS creates three layers?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am using QGIS 3.0.1.  Everytime I drag in a shapefile (actually, *.shp, .shx and .dbf) I get three layers, that seem to differ just in symbology color.  This happens with both shapefiles I get from outside sources and ones that I have generated in Python.  My colleagues using ArcGIS see just a single layer when they do the same operation.

This isn't a problem other than adding what looks like redundant layers - or maybe I do not understand something kind of basic here.

[image: Screen capture of three layers ("Photo_Pts") after dragging in one shapefile.]

Comment: Are you saying you drag in those *.shp, .shx and .dbf files?

Comment: just drag the .shp (qgis figures out the rest)

Comment: Thanks for the comments - yes - dragging JUST the .shp file in fixed my problem.  Thanks again.